# Use shell script to run python code, but it return 'invalid syntax' and 'No module named' error

Tags: python, linux, shell

'invalid syntax' error occurs first.

```
lzh@ubuntu:~/Graduation_Project/Code$ bash test.sh
  File "/home/lzh/Graduation_Project/Code/update_day.py", line 27
    print(day_url,end='')
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I try to delete  `end=' '`code and run it again.

but it return another error: 'No module named' error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lzh/Graduation_Project/Code/update_day.py", line 4, in <module>
    from urllib.request import urlopen
ImportError: No module named request
```

but it can run on Terminal successfully. Why?

```
lzh@ubuntu:~/Graduation_Project/Code$ python /home/lzh/Graduation_Project/Code/update_day.py
https://vup.darkflame.ga/api/summary/2022/3/6   done
```

Python(3.6.9) code:

```
# coding: utf-8
#! /bin/env python3

from urllib.request import urlopen
import urllib
import pandas as pd
import time
tlist = time.localtime()
# column = ['date','income', 'pay_num','danmu']
try_times = 20
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0'}
year = tlist[0]
month = tlist[1]
day = tlist[2]
List = []
day_list = [31,0,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
if day == 1:
    if month == 2:
        if (year%4 == 0 and year%100!=0 or year%400==0):
            day=29
        else:
            day=28
    else:
        day = day_list[month-1]

day_url = 'https://vup.darkflame.ga/api/summary/'+str(year)+'/'+str(month)+'/'+str(day-1)
print(day_url,end='')
```

shell script code:

```
#! /bin/bash
#! /bin/env python3
python '/home/lzh/Graduation_Project/Code/update_day.py'
```

system version:Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Comment: Is it a possibility that you have two different versions of Python installed on your machine?

Comment: Change from `python` to `python3`. The `#! /bin/env python3` is not doing anything at all.

Comment: (Also, a shebang is properly written `#!/bin/bash`, **without a space**)

Comment: BTW, why are you doing this in the first place instead of just making a symlink?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is written for Python 3, but you're running it with a Python 2 interpreter.

If you want to use `python3` instead of `python`, you need to specify that:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec python3 '/home/lzh/Graduation_Project/Code/update_day.py'
```

The `exec` is there for better performance (because it makes `sh` *replace itself with* Python instead of spawning a subprocess to exec the Python interpreter in) -- take `exec` out if `python3` is ever no longer the last line of your script.

(using `sh` instead of `bash` because nothing you're doing here takes advantage of bash's features, and sh is faster to start).

Comment: I have changed my Ubuntu default Python version to 3.6.9. So I think it is running on Python3. I'm not good at Shell script. And Thank you so much!

Comment: _How_ you changed the default matters. If you did it with an alias, f/e, that only impacts your interactive shell; it doesn't change behavior of scripts.